# array to string conversion in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Please help me guys, i have a problem when i try to make a dropdown list using pluck function.

this is my controller code

```
public function tambah()
{
    $jabatan = jabatan::pluck('nama_jab', 'id_jab')->toArray();
    return view('anggota.tambah',compact('jabatan'));
}
```

and this is my view code

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" id="ruangan_id">Jabatan</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    {!! Form::select('id_jab',$jabatan,null,['class'=>'form-control','id_jab'=>'id_jab','placeholder'=>"Jabatan"]) !!}
</div>
```

this is model for jabatan

```
protected $table=['jabatan'];
public function anggota(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\anggota');
}
```

this is model for anggota

```
protected $table = 'anggota';
protected $guarded=['id'];

public function jabatan(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\jabatan');
}
```

i want to show this data to my dropdown list

```
id_jab  nama_jab
1       manager
2       ka.divisi
3       staff
4       pekerja
```

end the error message:

> ErrorException in Grammar.php line 36:
>   Array to string conversion

please help me

Comment: Try except `$jabatan = jabatan::pluck('nama_jab', 'id_jab')->toArray();` use `$jabatan = jabatan::pluck('nama_jab', 'id_jab')->all();`

Comment: So, what is on line 36 of `gramar.php`?

Comment: Post more code where the error occurs to help you. Your fetching and using of the data in the form select is correct. I do this as well.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of:

```
$jabatan = jabatan::pluck('nama_jab', 'id_jab')->toArray();
```

use:

```
$jabatan = jabatan::pluck('nama_jab', 'id_jab');
```

Or:

```
$jabatan = jabatan::get()->pluck('nama_jab', 'id_jab');
```

Comment: The code he uses is absolutely fine and you're code is wrong.

Comment: @Sandeesh, it's clear you love to downvote. how it's wrong and I used it like that many time. don't downvote without check or be sure.

Comment: Can you see him using the plucked result in the form select? Now go test your result and see if it works with the form select, it won't since you need an array for that. I downvoted you because you posted this without even thinking about the context of the author's problem.

Comment: I never used `->toArray()` with `->pluck()`. he used it and have a problem. for that I tell him to use it without `->pluck()`. after he does, only he can tell us work or not.

Comment: If your way it's right doesn't mean the other way is wrong. you just love to downvote. also, you do it, judge without a test.

Comment: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#drop-down-lists should put some sense. That was my second downvote ever. I'm done trying to explain. Good day.

Comment: I used **laravelcollective** in all projects I developed not new for me. And the point is, if you love way, don't blame the other way. and think twice before downvote again.